# JavaScript/JQuery/HTML - Use output of one script as variable in another script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a small chrome extension. Its purpose is to make an API call to retrieve some JSON which is then stripped out to show only `Name, Email & Team` which is then presented to the user. The user then has the option to send that information to a slack channel via a button.

Everything works fine, my API call shows the correct information, My Webhook for slack works fine with a test message.

My issue is I dont know how to put whats returnd from my API call as variables to send to slack

```
$('.Name').html(data.user.name);
$('.Email').html(data.user.email);
$('.Teams').html(data.user.teams[0].name);
```

I.e.

```
var text = '$('.Name') + 'was contacted from' + $('.Teams') + 'Their email addres is' + $('.Email')''
```

Example slack message

```
John Smith was contacted from Sales Team Their email address is jsmith@mysite.com
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots">
    <meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="googlebot">
    <script src="jquery-git.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='apicall.js'></script>
    <script src='slackapi.js'></script>
    <title>Call Logger</title>
</head>
<style>
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Call Logger</h3><br>
    <h2><div class="Name"></h2>
    <h2><div class="Address"></h2>
    <h2><div class="Teams"></h2>
    <h2><div class="Email"></div></h2>
    <h2><div class="Role"></div></h2>
    <br>
    <br>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Send</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**apicall.js**

```
function currentUrl() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    chrome.tabs.query({
      active: true,
      currentWindow: true
    }, function(tabs) {
      resolve(tabs[0].url)
    })
  })
}

function userIdfromUrl(url) {
  var parts = url.split('/')
  return parts[parts.length - 1]
}
var authorizationToken = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
function myapiRequest(endpoint, options) {
    $.ajax($.extend({}, {
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
    $('.Name').html(data.user.name);
    $('.Email').html(data.user.email);
    $('.Teams').html(data.user.teams[0].name);
},

    url: "https://api.myapi.com/" + endpoint,
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Token token=" + authorizationToken,
      "Accept": "application/vnd.myapi+json;version=2"
    }
  },
  options));
}
currentUrl()
  .then(function (url) {
    return userIdfromUrl(url)
  })
  .then(function (userId) {
    return myapiRequest('users/' + userId + '?include%5B%5D=contact_methods&include%5B%5D=teams')
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data.user.name)
    console.log(data.user.email)
    console.log(data.user.teams[0].name)
  })
```

**slackapi.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contact-submit').on('click',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        var text = 'This is a message'
        $.ajax({
            data: 'payload=' + JSON.stringify({
                "text": text // What I want to dynamically change
            }),
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: url
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obviously can't reproduce your setup, but, depending on what kind of pages are `apicall.js` and `slackapi.js` - there are some restrictions and particularities in the case of content/background pages -, I think you can send the text variable (or even its constituent parts, e.g. name, teams, email, using an array) to `slackapi.js` by [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging).

You send the message from `apicall.js` usually using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` (other options are available, depending on context), and you receive the message using a listener, e.g. `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener()`. For the message to be received, `slackapi.js` or any other JS file needs to run, so if it doesn't it needs to be injected using `chrome.tabs.executeScript()`, for example.

I'm not sure if this will help you, but at least I tried.